# Piercing Knots Ay?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, chakras, kundalini

Granthi is a Sanskrit Name for a Knot. In all Chakra meditation, Kundalini related books, one can find this 'neural knots' mentioned in the path of an ascent of a yogi. The 7 chakras & the associated( at least ) 3 knots. Brahma Granthi, Vishnu Granthi & Rudra Granthi.
I'm disappointed that Not ONE book, not ONE article talks about unknotting these knots. They always talk about Mudras & Yoga poses to Pierce the knots! Pierce! Really?

Here For e.g. https://www.prana-sutra.com/post/the-three-granthis-yoga-brahma-vishnu-rudra.

Here are the verses relating to these, from Lalitha Sahasranamam.

Muladharaika Nilaya Brahma Granthi Vibhedini

Manipuraantharuditha vishnu granthi vibhedini

Ajna chakraantharalastha
Rudra Granthi Vibhedini

All the Yogis & Self-realized Swamins & other honorable members in this group...Please explain to me...When you find a knot what are you supposed to do? Unknot it or Pierce it?  Do we 'pierce' a Shoe Lace knot? Do we Pierce the Sailor's knot with which an anchored Ship is tied to the Pier? Do we pierce any knot at all? Then Why Piercing is mentioned invariably in every article or book in the context of THESE Knots. Don't you find it very odd? Some trickery(Tantra) involved correct? If it is a knot, aren't we supposed to unknot it EVEN if it is one of the Granthis? Then isn't piercing illegal? All the enlightenment you have attained becomes illegal. Correct. You are supposed to live through Muladharas knotted problems experience in Mundane world and still come out of it properly resolving your life's mundane troubles to unknot Brahma Granthi. isn't it?  You are supposed to live through an Egoless life even with riches ( like Janaka) for unknotting Vishnu Granthi.  You are supposed to live through an Intellectual but humility-filled phase & recognize the divinity before unknotting Rudra Granthi. Isn't it?

These knots also are for unknotting. correct. Not piercing. That is my concrete understanding.
I feel Misguided by these and these books/articles does not put forth the original intentions very well. Piercing is obviously a short cut!

Appreciate your response on Why Piercing is mentioned & any scriptural source associated...If you can't find any..any Valid justification would suffice...Thanks!

Comment: The justification is inside the heart, not in the mind. Why would be benificial for a human getting pierced without devotion, without any meaning?

Comment: Of course, you ought to have devotion. Of course, piercing your skin has a meaning. Just that you can't pierce away your problems. The Granthis are in ascent soul paths. You have to unknot them to resolve them. Janaka was a properly realized King. Yagnayavalkya had two wives. Do you think they didn't have problems? Solved every problem in their lives just by being Good hearted. Think again. You are seeking powers beyond Mundane on the ascent. Do you think that you will not be tested for that? The heart alone is sufficient? There is always an Enlightenment Seeker well-roundedness requirement.